# Saved webpage has images that only open in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, html, webpage

I right-clicked a webpage in Chrome and saved as "Webpage, Complete". This webpage opens fine in Chrome, but some images don't load when I try to open it using other browsers like Firefox.

I checked the folder containing all the images and discovered that some of the jpg files cannot be opened (except in Chrome), and have no thumbnail, dimension, resolution or bit depth information. However, some of the jpg files do have thumbnails and dimensions etc. These open fine in other applications like Photos or Firefox.

All photos can be opened by themselves (without the rest of the saved webpage) in Chrome.

Whats going on? How can I save a webpage with Chrome while making sure the images can open in other browsers?

Comment: Maybe they are actually webp format. https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/

Comment: Huh, I just tried a webp-to-jpg converter and it seems to have worked. I can open the converted file. This is surprising to me because the original file was typed as a jpg not a webp... I guess it actually wasn't a jpg!

Comment: Came back to this and found a solution that works for me. Thanks @Appleoddity :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the "jpg" files were actually webp.

So a solution would be to use something like the [User-Agent Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg) extension on Chrome and select another browser that doesn't support webp (like Firefox). Then you can directly download webpages with all the images loaded as jpg instead of webp.

Or alternatively, download webpages as normal, and convert the webp files to jpg using other software (like [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)).